# When one domain is being hit, another is loaded

Tags: apache

I just removed some virtual hosts and restored them from backup.
I noticed that no matter what domain from the following i hit:

```
kidsclubpaidika.gr
ypsilandio.gr
varsa.gr
```

always my hit gets instantly redirected to domain `kidsclubpaidika.gr`instead.

Why is this happening?
I use Webmin/virtualmin btw.

here is my relevant httpd.conf https://pastebin.com/vzwbzTh8

Comment: I did notice this: `<VirtualHost 176.223.129.220:443 [fe80::21c:42ff:fe91:a981]:80>` in your first VirtualHost.  Do not mix :443 with :80.  This will conflict with the next VirtualHost which is `:443 ... :443`

Comment: Does `zoevax` demonstrate the same issue? I ask because `kidsclubpaidika.gr` is the last VirtualHost - top to bottom - in your configuration.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong in this configuration, besides the port I commented out above.  Do you have redirections in your PHP code that would redirect the user?  To validate that, start Chrome, F12 to view developper tools, see network, check "preserve logs", try varsa.gr.  You will see what responses you are getting, and if there is a 302 or 301 redirection.

Comment: I was able to fix this! I found an option of 'Website Options' that is aksing if this is the primary site for that domain and then i am able to see all that pages correctly.

Comment: Could you post what you applied?  I am curious and like to learn new details of Apache.

Comment: its was an option in the Virtualmin=>Website Options of the domain=>set as default

Comment: ah!  So not via editing httpd.conf.  Ok, I cannot help, I never use admin tools for Apache.  But my guess is that there is something wrong with the VirtualHosts, and the first one (from top to bottom) becomes the default when Apache cannot match the ServerName with the requested site.

Answer (score 0):

There's a FAQ about this kind of problem: https://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/web/troubleshooting#toc-the-wrong-site-shows-up-V5JtxdKg

The short description of the problem is that when combining VirtualHosts that use IP addresses and `*`, the way Apache decides what to show is unintuitive (to put it mildly). Mixing `*` and IP-based VirtualHosts is, thus, not recommended. So, find the virtual hosts that use `*` and switch them to IPs, or find all the IPs and switch them to `*`. Don't mix and match. I usually recommend using IPs, but either works, as long as you only have one IP.

If you have a default site (e.g. 000-default on Ubuntu/Debian), disable it. In a virtual hosting environment, "default" doesn't really have the same meaning and can lead to confusing results. The Virtualmin installer will do that for you, but doing a dist upgrade will lead to config files being overwritten and that site being re-enabled.

Comment: Hi, you should explain what the solution is, link only answers get rejected after review.  I read the FAQ, it talks about using the wrong IP address, but from the question, all his VirtualHosts are on 1 IP.

Comment: OK, I've added a brief summary. The problem is not about multiple IPs. It is about using `*` intermingled with IP-based VirtualHosts. There are other things that can cause it, all related to the way Apache selects which VirtualHost to respond with and all related to what's in the VirtualHost section, but this is the most common.